# Nest-able template format which is supported by both php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, template-engine

I've been using Mustache for a while and I've started itching to just a little bit of logic in the my templates.
I've been looking around at various template formats and am a little surprised that there are very few which have wide support for both server-side and client-side parsing.

I'm really looking for a format with:
1. a little bit of logic
2. nestable stuctures (i.e one can be called into another)
3. has both a PHP and JS parsing libraries

I have seen [this](https://github.com/abackstrom/jquery-tmpl-php) and [this](https://github.com/xyu/jquery-tmpl-php) but they both seem to have a very low uptake and do not 100% support the jquery tmpl format.

Has anyone come across something like this?